# Perl para desenvolvimento web

Tags: aplicação-web, perl

É possível utilizar o Perl para desenvolvimento web?

Nesse contexto, a linguagem oferece algum benefício, ou seja, existem problemas que ela resolve de forma mais eficaz do que em outras plataformas?

Comment: João, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! O formato de perguntas e resposta do StackOverflow não é adequado para discussões, como seria num Fórum. Além disso, sua pergunta contém muitas questões que acabam sendo baseadas em opiniões. Creio que principalmente por causa dessas razões, alguns usuários da comunidade suspenderam sua pergunta. No entanto, fique à vontade para fazer novas perguntas quando tiver dúvidas mais específicas. Opcionalmente, você pode editar sua pergunta e tentar deixá-la mais específica. Sugiro que leia [ask]. Abraço!

Comment: Agradeço mas no fim essa comunidade é exatamente como me falaram. Por ser cheia de regras acaba sendo chata. Um conhecimento empurrado guela abaixo quase tão bom como ler um livro de literatura dos anos 50. Isso parece um amontoado de parte teórica do modo mais massante possível. Primeira e última experiência aqui.

Comment: Regras do [pt.so] ou de qualquer site podem ser um pouco chatas de início, e temos vários pontos a melhorar, mas esta organização é o motivo pelo qual o SO é o site de programação mais acessado no mundo. Tentamos disponibilizar informação de forma objetiva e direta. Em qualquer fórum "comum" também há regras que você deve seguir e, embora tenha um pouco mais de liberdade na forma como se expressar, os tópicos ficam todos bagunçados e mal organizados sendo bem mais difícil de beneficiar outras pessoas.

Comment: Fiz uma reformulação na sua pergunta para que seja possível responder de forma mais objetiva. Se achar que não está de acordo você pode editá-la novamente conforme desejar.

Comment: Será que num fórum tem este tipo de ajudas como a do @utluiz? Não me parece. Sinta-se a vontade de perguntar, passe no nosso [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e veja como perguntar.

Answer (score 2):

Definitivamente é possível, por sinal há uns 10 ou 15 anos atrás era muito utilizada na web. Na época se chamava a parte server-side de CGI scripts, que eram em boa parte scripts Perl.

Acredito que se você tem familiaridade com ambiente UNIX, e com a linguagem, não terá muitos problemas.

Quanto a eficácia em comparação com outras linguagens, eu não sou familiar com nenhum campo em que Perl se sobressai em questão de performance.

Mas eu acho que é totalmente válido se for um projeto pequeno/pessoal seu e Perl for uma linguagem que você gosta ou quer aprender.

Para sistemas maiores, eu recomendo dar uma olhada no [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) ou outras plataformas mais populares, vai te facilitar a vida se precisar contratar programadores.

Comment: Só para complementar essa resposta: o booking.com é todo feito em Perl. Tanto que eles são considerados o "celeiro" de desenvolvedores Perl na Europa.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível desenvolver em Perl para WEB. O maior benefício são os módulos disponíveis no CPAN como auxílio para uma imensa quantidade de problemas já resolvidos. Até mesmo para a orientação a objetos, você tem diversas opções, como Moose, Class::Tiny ou Moo.

Como outras linguagens, Perl está em ativo desenvolvimento, e para o final do ano está previsto o lançamento do Perl6, mantendo o Perl5, como projetos separados, quase como linguagens distintas.

Quanto a linguagem a ser usada, a não ser em casos muito especiais como Erlang, não vão resolver problemas de forma particular. Aqui é mais uma questão de opinião e ecossistema que mais lhe agradem. Existem soluções similares quando se trabalha com PHP, Ruby, Perl ou Python.

No ecossistema Perl, você encontra três principais frameworks atualmente:

- Catalyst
- Mojolicious e Mojolicious::Lite
- Dancer2

Existem outras opções, mas essas três são a referência na comunidade.